# Trying to create a checking account class but running into issues

Tags: python, oop

> Write a class named “CheckingAccount” that contains the current
> balance of the account (an int) and the following methods:
>
> - init - takes a “balance” parameter to initialize the data (balance)of the object. Remember, the method init is implemented as
>   `___init__`.
> - withdraw - takes an input parameter “amount” and modifies the data by reducing the balance. If “amount” results in an overdraw,subtract
>   an extra 20 dollars. This method should return the balance.
> - deposit - takes an input parameter “amount” and modifies the data by increasing the balance by “amount”.

I'm trying to do the above problem but I'm kind of lost and this is the best I've got so far (updated code today):

```
# write your code here
class CheckingAccount:
    balance = 0
    amount = 0
    
    def __init__(self, balance = 0):
        self.balance = balance
        
    def withdraw(self, amount = 0):
        if self.amount > self.balance:
            self.balance -= 20
        else:
            self.balance -= 1
    def deposit(self, amount = 0):
        self.amount += amount
        return amount
        
an = CheckingAccount(80)
an.withdraw(40)
print("Your old balance was {}. Your new balance is now {}.".format(an.balance))
```

I'm getting closer but my old balance shows as 79 instead of 80 and my new balance shows as 0 when I think I was expecting 40. I feel like I'm missing something.

Comment: Yes, that looks fine, you just need to accept parameters for your withdraw and deposit methods.

Comment: This seems to be a schoolwork problem, please read [this](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems).
For your problem, you are on the right track. Notice that `withdraw` and `deposit` takes an input parameter. `self` is mandatory for a class method, so you need a second parameter for these methods, that will be the amount to withdraw or deposit

Comment: Then you can create a last method, let's call it `getBalance`, that will return you the current balance, so you can print it, and do some tests

Comment: @totok. I read the post. I get your viewpoint. That's why I do the code to the best of my ability and then reach out for help. I don't want anyone to do this problem completely for me. OOP's never been my strong suit and getting help through here is faster than getting it through my instructor. But I do try to do the problem as best as I can so as not overburden the other programmers on here. That's my justification for posting this one.

Comment: @runner16 Yep no problem, that's why I gave a comment about your work, you're doing fine ;) I just send it to anyone asking help for their homework as a prevention measure. Have you managed to achieve what you wanted ?

Comment: @totok, sadfully not yet but I think I'm getting closer. I updated my post with new code. I emailed my professor but he hasn't responded back yet. I figure he'll see what I'm doing wrong pretty quickly though. weird thing I've gotten the other questions with no problem. But I can't seem to get the very first one :/

Comment: You don't have to store the amount. Think of a simplified bank : They store your balance, and update it when you buy something or earn money. You don't have to store the amount of the last operation.Your wirthdraw method is almost good, I think the `else` part is useless, and, why did you withdraw `20` instead of `amount` ? Your deposit method needs to me reworked : don't store `amount`, just update the balance with the amount you want to deposit on.

Comment: Then, for the print part, you will need to store the old value of an.balance in a variable before calling the `withdraw` method, to be able to print both the old and the new value

Answer (score 0):

```
class CheckingAccount:
    balance = 0
    oldbalance = 0
    #amount = 0
   
    def __init__(self, balance = 0):
        self.balance = balance
       
    def withdraw(self, amount = 0):
        self.oldbalance = self.balance
        if amount < self.balance:
            self.balance -= amount
            print("Amount withdrawn {}".format(amount))
        else:
            self.balance -= amount + 20
            print("Amount withdraw ${} with penalty of $20".format(amount))
        
    def deposit(self, amount = 0):
        self.oldbalance = self.balance
        self.balance += amount
        return amount
       
an = CheckingAccount(80)
an.withdraw(10)
print("Your old balance was {}. Your new balance is now {}.".format(an.oldbalance, an.balance))
```

Comment: @totok, apologies for the delay. I got a response back from my professor. To your point, the reason I wasn't trying to withdraw 20. I was trying to add a penalty of 20 if a person overdrafted like in the real world. My code just wasn't coming out that way. :/ I was able to get the help from him and this is what I got which is pretty neat code. I do appreciate your help with this though!